# como eliminar o remplazar \ de una cadena de texto

Tags: python

Buenas tardes tengo un string que es una ruta de windows c:\user\x pero quiero eliminar las lineas o cambiarlas "\" sin embargo me marca un error al tratar de hacerlo este es mi codigo:

```
 string = "C:\User\New\Desktop"
 s_replace = string.replace("\"," ")
```

pero me no funciono

Comment: Las barras comunes deben escaparse con la doble barra: primero: `string = "C:\\User\\New\\Desktop"` y luego entonces sí string.replace("\\"," ")

Comment: Python2 o Python3?

Comment: Hola Rs_sky ¿Usas Python 3? ¿De dónde viene realmente la variable?¿De `input`?¿De algún Entry de una GUI?¿De un fichero?, lo digo porque la línea `string = "C:\User\New\Desktop"` como tal es inválida ocasionando un `SyntaxError` en Python 3 a causa de `\U`, ¿no tendrás en realidad`"C:\\User\\New\\Desktop"`? Lo puedes comprobar con `print(repr(string))`.  En ese caso podrías usar `replace("\\", " ")`.

Comment: @FJSevilla, el string lo recibo despues de ejecutar un os.walk() para obtener la ruta de un fichero, pero me devuelve la ruta solamente con un \ no con \\ como menciona Patricio,

Comment: @FJSevilla, y uso python3

Comment: Pues si te lo devuelve con una sola barra / agregale otra y listo

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez, podrias indicarme como puedo hacerlo

Comment: No sabría hacerlo en python pero en java y .net se haria un sting.split("\") es decir dividiria la cadena a partir de la barra me devolvera un array string por lo que con un ciclo a cada elemento excepto el ultimo de la cadena le agrego "\\" y al terminar el ciclo lo almaceno en un solo string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas deseas eliminarlas usa  `s_replace = string.replace("\","")`

Comment: El OP dice claramente que había probado exactamente eso (`s_replace = string.replace("\"," ")`) y no le había funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución:

```
import os

print('\\')
for r, d, f in os.walk("C:\\"):
    for files in f:
        if files == "WINWORD.EXE":

            print(os.path.join(r,files))
            r = os.path.join(r,files)
            res = r.replace('\\','\\\\') #escapando \ 2 veces obtengo el resultado deseaso
            print(res)

            break
```

**Resultado: **

```
\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE
```

Comment: Rs_sky  `os.path` te devuelve la ruta correctamente con las barras escapadas, al mostrarlas con `print` no se muestran, pero la cadena las tiene.Por eso te comenté arriba que usaras `print(repr(r))` para que te mostrara el contenido verdadero de la cadena.La ruta tal y como te la retorna `os.path.join` es perfectamente válida,no tienes que añadirle nada.Tu cadena ahora es en realidad `C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Office\\\\root\\\\Office16\\\\WINWORD.EXE`.  `print` lógicamente procesa las secuencias de escape, lo mismo que `print("Hola\n")` no imprime `\n` realiza un salto de línea.

Answer (score 0):

lo que digo es que para eliminar el caracter, debe poner las comillas sin un espacio, es decir: `s_replace = string.replace("\", "")` y no `s_replace = string.replace("\", " ")`, ya que al poner un espacio entre las comillas esta tratando de cambiar `"\"` por `" "` , lo otro que sugiero que haga entes de quitar el caracter es que haga esto: `string = str(string)` por si el formato que tiene es  `None`